# How to define a Task properly in APEX Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am new to tasks definition, and i need help regarding that! I made a simple hotel reservation app, in which the first task is for a guest to create a reservation, and then the receptionist to activate that reservation. I defined a task for activating reservation with the following definition:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHspy.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NK2d.png)

I saw that there are API calls for the tasks related stuff, so I insert the reservation into the table and then create the approval task:
[insertion process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CafGH.png)
[task creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igx8E.png)

However, when i try to execute the processes, I get the following [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LctAM.png).

Can anyone tell me why is it not working and what am I missing? How do I make it work? I followed the tutorial written on the Oracle site regarding tasks creation.

EDIT 1: If I swap the Action Source setting in the task definition menu from SQL Query to None, the processes execute. As you can notice [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOJYG.png), I even get Task ID. But when trying to see all the tasks available, I get no data found as a response as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFPgN.png).